# Securing Trunk on a Civic

Tags: civic

I have a 2010 Civic. If I have to transport stuff that sticks out of the trunk and won't allow it to close, how can I do this?

Normally, in other cars, you can take a bungee cord (which I have), connect it from some latch on the trunk door to something on the bottom.

I couldn't find anything suitable on the trunk door though for this; the actual closing mechanism is like an inverted V-shape, and there's nothing I can clasp the cord to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's REALLY nothing to attach to, one thing that comes into mind is something similar to trunk bike rack. One end of your cord goes outside of the trunk, near the back window, and second part goes under bumper. something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffp0r11E7Tg